# Insert script adds N before each varchar data

Tags: oracle, import, scripting, oracle-sql-developer

I exported results from a query in order to import it into a table on another DB. I chose the xlsx output format and verified that the data had gotten written to the excel file. While trying to import it into the table, I chose to create an insert script so that I could go over the final data before importing it. On doing this, I noticed that all the varchar fields have a N character right before the opening quote, making it look like:

`INSERT INTO ... ()
VALUES(N'...', 0.0, N'....')`

Any ideas on why this might be happening and how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text literals with `N` (or `n`) in front of the opening quote indicate that the strings may contain symbols from a national character set, that is, they have the data type `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. Either the target columns have these data types, or SQL Developers assumes that from the database NLS settings.

You can find [more details in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm).

Comment: Thank you! I was thrown off by the extra N, and didn't realize that running the script with it wouldn't cause an issue.